# Input types in text fields in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Please describe features of input types in Eclipse

I'm trying to write an application for Android in Eclipse with ADT (or ADP, dunno), i have a text field with an input type called "Person name". 
I thought this input type will capitalize words, but it doesn't do it - i tried to run it on AVD and it doesn't even capitalizes words, it also prevents me from typing uppercase.

Is it my fault or is it some error in AVD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Xml set the  input type of your edittext to

**android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"**

this will allow you to type capital letters